# Grails spring-security-ldap plugin is not working

Tags: grails-plugin

I am trying to use Grails spring-security-ldap plugin for LDAP authentication with my Grails 2.0.1 application. I followed the instructions for this plugin. Now how can I start the login page?

Should I run s2-quickstart from spring-secuity-core plugin to generate user/roles?

Comment: not really familiar with Grails, but you should try adding your OS name/version so people can help you find what you need faster

Comment: Given that it's Grails, it's unlikely to be related to the OS.